# What is the impact of sslverify and strict-ssl for salesforcedx?

Tags: security, salesforcedx

In the documentation for installing salesforcedx behind a firewall ( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm ) it suggests we perform the following:

```
npm config set https-proxy https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set proxy https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set sslVerify false
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

I understand that this is changing the configuration for npm, but what do the following two lines actually do, and what are the security implications?

```
npm config set sslVerify false
npm config set strict-ssl false
```